# Installation error LUBUNTU 20.04.4 LTS

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu

I had already installed Lubuntu 20.04 LTS  on my laptop but it seemed slow and sluggish so I downloaded an ISO and verified it, burned the USB using balena etcher(not the first time that I did this).

When I try to install it I run into the following issue:

```
The installer failed to create a partition cable on HGST HTS545050A7E380

Create a new partition table (type: gpt) on /dev/sda

Job: Create new partition table on device /dev/sda

Command: sfdisk /dev/sda
```

I am using the same used and password as in the previous way that I have, but I don't think that that's the issue.

Can it be that I'm trying to install the same distro that I have already installed?

If I can verify the version already installed I would prefer that, although every solution will he appreciated.

Comment: Your pasted error message makes no sense (typos; I assume it wasn't copy/pasted), but if `calamares` (the installer used by Lubuntu) has issues; you can/could-have used KDE Partition Manager to create the file-system you needed, then used `calamares` to select partitions & installed that way. Ubuntu & Lubuntu use the same core installation code; the GUI/installer front-end is really what differs

Answer (score 0):

The error was solved when I Installed ubuntu 20.04 LTS and then tried to reinstall LUBUNTU 20.04 LTS

Comment: Well done for solving it; I suspect all you did was do the partitioning using the `ubiquity` instead which you could have done with the Lubuntu ISO using KDE Partition Manager.. Of note - if you get a bad error in `calamares` I'd suggest reboot before trying again, as it can get '*confused*' after an error and re-tries do fail in subsequent tries. But well done for getting around your issue.